# How to trigger a mouseDown:(NSEvent *) programmatically (without using the mouse)?

Tags: macos, mouse, mouseevent

I am developing a Leap Motion Application where I already move the cursor with it, but I don't know how I can trigger a mouseDown:(NSEvent *) programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

This worked well for me ***in Cocoa Mac***:

```
void PostMouseEvent(CGMouseButton button, CGEventType type, const CGPoint point)
{
   CGEventRef theEvent = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(NULL, type, point, button);
   CGEventSetType(theEvent, type);
   CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, theEvent);
   CFRelease(theEvent);
}
```

Use this link to find out about the parameters: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html

For example, to trigger a MouseDown event at the point (500,500) I've used:

```
PostMouseEvent(kCGMouseButtonLeft, NX_LMOUSEDOWN, CGPointMake(200, 200));
```